# Cocos2D BezierBy with increasing speed over time

Tags: c++, ios, performance, cocos2d-x

I'm pretty new to C++/Cocos2d, but I've been making pretty good progress. :)

What I want to do is animate a coin 'falling off' the screen after a player gets it. I've managed to successfully implement it 2 different ways, but each way has major downsides.

The goal: After a player gets a coin, the coin should 'jump', then 'fall' off of the screen. Ideally, the coin acts as if acted upon by gravity, so it jumps up with a fast speed, slows down to a stop, then proceeds to go downward at an increasing rate.

Attempts so far:

```
  void Coin::tick(float dt) {
    velocityY += gravity * dt;
    float newX = coin->getPositionX() + velocityX;
    float newY = coin->getPositionY() + velocityY;
    coin->setPosition(newX, newY);
    // using MoveBy(dt, Vec2(newX, newY)) has same result
  }
  // This is run on every 'update' of the main game loop.
```

This method does exactly what I would like it to do as far as movement, however, the frame rate gets extremely choppy and it starts to 'jump' between frames, sometimes quite significant distances.

```
  ccBezierConfig bz;
  bz.controlPoint_1 = Vec2(0, 0);
  bz.controlPoint_2 = Vec2(20, 50); // These are just test values. Will normally be randomized to a degree.
  bz.endPosition = Vec2(100, -2000);
  auto coinDrop = BezierBy::create(2, bz);
  coin->runAction(coinDrop);
```

This one has the benefit of 'perfect' framerate, where there is no choppiness whatsoever, however, it moves at a constant rate which ruins the experience of it falling and just makes it look like it's arbitrarily moving along some set path. (Which, well, it is.)

Has anybody run into a similar situation or know of a fix? Either to better handle the frame rate of the first one (MoveBy/To don't work- still has the choppy effect) or to programmatically set speeds of the second one (change speeds going to/from certain points in the curve)

Another idea I've had is to use a number of different `MoveBy` actions with different speeds, but that would have awkward 'pointy' curves and awkward changes in speed, so not really a solution.

Any ideas/help are/is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have run into a similar situation. This is where 'easing' comes in handy. There are many built in easing functions that you can use such as Ease In or Ease Out. So your new code would look something like:

`coin->runAction(cocos2d::EaseBounceOut::create(coinDrop));`

This page shows the graphs for several common easing methods:
http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/programmers-guide/4/index.html

For your purposes (increasing speed over time) I would recommend trying the 'EaseIn' method.